# Display data from database inside a readonly textfield

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, laravel, postgresql

so I am trying to show the first, middle and last name used in registration here. how should I do it? I am new to laravel so it is my first time encountering this scenario

```
 <div class=" overflow-auto">
                <div class="p-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title text-info"><strong> Step 1 (Application Form: Personal Information)</strong></h4>
                            <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label for="firstName" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">First Name</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" id='firstName'  readonly>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label for="middleName" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">Middle Name</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" required="" placeholder="Middle Name" id='middleName'  readonly>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label for="lastName" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">Last Name</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" required="" placeholder="Last Name" id='lastName'  readonly>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <a href="step2" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-success"  style="float:right;">Next</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass your variables into your views, and echo like this :

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{ $firstName }}" id='firstName'  readonly>
```

You must read more about blade templates.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#displaying-data

Comment: How do i query it in the controller?

Comment: Define your models and relationships.